# How can I print a PowerShell hash object as a hash object?

Tags: powershell, hash, format

If I have a PowerShell hash object, how can I output it's contents in a format that can be used to declare a PowerShell hash object literal?

As a simple example, say you initialize a variable $x as follows:

```
$x = @{
  a = 1
  b = 2
  c = @{
    foo = "bar"
  }
}
```

If you just enter `$x` you'll get a tabular view:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                        
----                           -----                                                                                                        
c                              {foo}                                                                                                        
b                              2                                                                                                            
a                              1
```

I know there are other formatters, but I didn't find one that formats it back out as a pretty-printed PowerShell literal, something like how I declared it above.

Comment: perhaps use a format that can be read back into an object.  Like `$x | ConvertTo-Json`.

Comment: My question was all about the output format.  The "ConvertTo-Expression" answer below is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [`ConvertTo-Expression`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression) cmdlet can serialize most (recursive) objects to a PowerShell expression:

```
$x | ConvertTo-Expression
@{
        'c' = @{'foo' = 'bar'}
        'b' = 2
        'a' = 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you had in mind, but you could always declare your variable as a scriptblock using the `{}` notation. Then you can call (`&`) the scriptblock when you want a hashtable output. So when you enter `$x`, you can preserve your original formatting.

```
# Declaration
$x = {@{
a = 1
b = 2
c = @{
  foo = "bar"
}
}}

#Retrieval of $x contents
$x
@{
a = 1
b = 2
c = @{
  foo = "bar"
}
}

# Calling the scriptblock
& $x

Name                           Value
----                           -----
c                              {foo}
b                              2
a                              1
```

Comment: Sounds like I need to clarify the question.  I'm looking for a way to *output* in the PowerShell hash syntax.  Much like ConvertTo-Json but not JSON format, PowerShell hash literal format.